# aligned equations with mathjax, and with equation numbers

Tags: python-sphinx, mathjax, numbered

I would like to write a series of numbered equations aligned at the equality sign. Like the usual `.. math::` with multiple equations, but wrapped in `\begin{align} ... \end{align}`  rather than `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`. Is there a way to do that with sphinx? Or perhaps an extension?

**EDIT:** I need equation numbers so that I can refer to those from the main text using the `:ref:` role.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\label` and `\tag` to manually add equation labels; this works in both MathJax and LaTeX (for pdf output).

E.g.,

```
\[ \bigcap \emptyset = \{ x : x = x\} \label{test} \tag{an equation} \]
```

For a live example, see http://codepen.io/pkra/pen/hyktl

Comment: I need to refer to the equation number via `:ref:` in the main text, and sphinx knows nothing about `\label` inside mathjax. I edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm not a sphinx expert. FWIW, TeX and MathJax expect similar things, i.e. `\ref` to generate references.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:nowrap:` to allow you to provide your own wrapping and `:label:` to crerate a label, which you can reference using `:eq:`. For example:

```
So we arrive at the important equations

.. math::
   :label: important
   :nowrap:

   \begin{align}
     ...
   \end{align}

This set of equations :eq:`important` gives rise to...
```

For my source and more details, see [the Sphinx documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/math.html).

Comment: Did you actually try this?

Comment: @eudoxos: I used both `:label:` and `:nowrap:` today (Sphinx 1.2.2), although not together. Does it not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It is an old issue but the solution working for me is not described here and difficult to find on the web.
It simply consists in line-break inside math instruction :

```
.. math::
   :label: important

   F_{x} &=\int_{S} \sigma_{x x} d S 
   & 
   M_{x} &=\int_{S}\left(y \sigma_{x z}-z \sigma_{x y}\right) d S  
   
   F_{y} &=\int_{S} \sigma_{x y} d S  
   &
   M_{y} &=\int_{S} z \sigma_{x x} d S  
   
   F_{z} &=\int_{S} \sigma_{x z} d S 
   & 
   M_{z} &=-\int_{S} y \sigma_{x x} d S
```

With this line-break, Sphinx would use the `align` environment of Latex
instead of `equation`+`split`.
It works for both html and latex output.